# Calling a method in custom XML class returns null

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to call a method that has some xml functionality and It keeps coming up null. What I am trying to do is; I have a page that has four dynamic text fields that get their content from an xml file. I would like to create a method that will output the contents to display in the dynamic field. Maybe my approach is WAY off here, but my supervisor wants all xml related tasks contained in a xml.as file.

Main.as

```
package classes
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    import classes.Xml; /* my custom class */

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main():void
        {
            var xml:Xml = new Xml("menu.xml"); 
            trace(xml.getCourseTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Xml.as

```
package classes
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Xml extends MovieClip
    {
        private var xml:XML;
        private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        public function Xml(p:String):void
        {
            loader.load(new URLRequest(p));
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,processXML);   
        }
        public function processXML():void
        {
            xml = new XML(loader.data)
            trace(xml); /* this will trace all xml data in xml file */ 
        }
        public function getCourseTitle():String
        {
            return xml.@title; /* this is supossed to return Test Course */ 

        }       
    }
}
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <course title="Test Course">
        <folder name="Question 1" link="1_1.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 2" link="1_2.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 3" link="1_3.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 4" link="1_4.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 5" link="1_5.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 6" link="1_6.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 7" link="1_7.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 8" link="1_8.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 9" link="1_9.swf"/>
   <folder name="Question 10" link="1_10.swf"/>
    </course>
```

Comment: Because your trying to access your xml object before the url loader has loaded your xml file, however the real question is, why does your `Xml` class subclass `MovieClip`?

Comment: Good question and don't know the question. I have seen some xml examples and it seems most use `EventDispatcher`. Is that what I should be using for this, or is there a better option? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

**Main.as**(document class):

```
package 
{
    import com.example.CourseXML;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var courseXml:CourseXML = new CourseXML("xml/course.xml");
            courseXml.addEventListener(CourseXML.LOAD_COMPLETE, onCourseXmlLoadComplete);
            trace(courseXml.title)// output: null

        }// end function

        private function onCourseXmlLoadComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            var courseXml:CourseXML = CourseXML(e.target);
            trace(courseXml.title) // output: Test Course

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**CouseXML.as**:

```
package com.example 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class CourseXML extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public static const LOAD_COMPLETE:String = "loadComplete";

        private var _urlLoader:URLLoader;
        private var _xml:XML;

        public function get title():String 
        {
            var title:String;

            try 
            {
                title = _xml.@title; 
            }
            catch (e:TypeError)
            {
                title = null;

            }// end catch

            return title;

        }// end function

        public function CourseXML(url:String) 
        {
            _urlLoader = new URLLoader();
            _urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUrlLoaderComplete);
            _urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));

        }// end function

        private function onUrlLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            _xml = XML(URLLoader(e.target).data);

            dispatchEvent(new Event(CourseXML.LOAD_COMPLETE));

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

If your wondering about the `try` and `catch` in the `CourseXML` object's `title()` getter method, I put that there so if you try and access any of the `_xml` property's members before the xml file is loaded and assigned to it, you don't get a nasty `TypeError`.

**[UPDATE]**

Upon second thought, the try and catch was unnecessary, it would have been easier to use a conditional statement like the following:

```
public function get title():String 
{
    return (_xml) ? _xml.@title : null;

}// end function
```

Comment: Wow, very nice. I actually figured out another way to do it and I was posting the new code until I saw your response. I really like your code better so I am going to use it. Thank you so much for your help, this will help me out a lot.

Comment: I do have one question for you; why would `Sprite` be better than `MovieClip` for my subclass?

Comment: It wouldn't, I extended `EventDispatcher` for `CourseXML`. It was for the document class that I extended `Sprite` instead of `MovieClip`. It's better if you don't need any extra properties and methods that come along with `MovieClip` in your document class.

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot, I didn't need the try and catch, just an if statement to test to see if `_xml` was null or not, going to change it now.

Comment: Thank you so much ,very nice work. I have not had the chance to play with it, but tomorrow when I get to work I am all over it. Thank you for taking the time to help me :-)